# NullPointerException when querying with Apache Drill to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-drill

I am querying to my `s3` bucket with `apache drill` in the following way:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> use s3;
+-------+---------------------------------+
|  ok   |             summary             |
+-------+---------------------------------+
| true  | Default schema changed to [s3]  |
+-------+---------------------------------+
1 row selected (1.182 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> show tables;
+--+
|  |
+--+
+--+
No rows selected (1.438 seconds)
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local>
```

The same  occurs with a regular `select`:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select * from s3.`directory/file.csv` limit 10;
oct 28, 2015 11:13:51 AM org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException <init>
GRAVE: org.apache.calcite.sql.validate.SqlValidatorException: Table '/denue/DENUE_INEGI_01_.csv' not found
oct 28, 2015 11:13:51 AM org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteException <init>
GRAVE: org.apache.calcite.runtime.CalciteContextException: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 42: Table '/denue/DENUE_INEGI_01_.csv' not found
Error: PARSE ERROR: From line 1, column 15 to line 1, column 42: Table '/denue/DENUE_INEGI_01_.csv' not found


[Error Id: 560c6ec3-e4b0-4fe3-8b32-fd3fa56e1dd1 on heliodromus:31010] (state=,code=0)
```

The same thing happens if I use `select * from`directory/file.csv`;`

What I am doing wrong?

My Storage plugin file is the following:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "enabled": true,
  "connection": "s3n://accessKeyId:secretAccesKey@red-queen/",
  "workspaces": {},
  "formats": {
    "psv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tbl"
      ],
      "delimiter": "|"
    },
    "csv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "csv"
      ],
      "delimiter": ","
    },
    "tsv": {
      "type": "text",
      "extensions": [
        "tsv"
      ],
      "delimiter": "\t"
    },
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    },
    "json": {
      "type": "json"
    },
    "avro": {
      "type": "avro"
    }
  }
}
```

Where obviously `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` are changed ...

`red-queen` is my `s3 bucket`, and inside the bucket is `directory` as a folder.

Comment: please try using backticks and your dir name: USE `s3`.`directory`; 
SHOW files; //should list file
SELECT * FROM `filename.extension`; Sorry, backticks do not show up in this comment. See answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try using backticks and your directory name:

```
USE `s3`.`directory`; 
SHOW files; //should list file
SELECT * FROM `filename.extension`;
```

Take a look at this [Drill pull request](https://github.com/StevenMPhillips/drill/commit/bd9d73b56091e9c97e819b85af59727847d95e55) and [blog](http://drill.apache.org/blog/2014/12/09/running-sql-queries-on-amazon-s3/).